# Possible to send request directly to Amazon SQS from http (javascript client)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to send a messaging request to Amazon's SQS directly from javascript?  I'm trying to create a logging system and would love to bypass sending the request to a middleman server.  Also, does anybody know of any alternatives to this solution that I may leverage?

Comment: Is this server-side Javascript (e.g. Node.js) or running in browsers/clients?

Comment: client side.  and just to clarify, you can overcome cross domain limitations by using script injection and setting the script element's src to the rest url.  if amazon offered to accept an optional callback parameter with which to wrap the response json object, this would be a standard JSONP call.  For any of you that care, you can read more about it here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 8):

SQS(and as a matter of fact all aws services) expose REST based apis. You can directly make a http request to the SQS REST api through javascript code. The api documentation id given [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/).

Comment: The browsers Same-Origin Policy will prevent this. Unless the OP is talking about server-side Javascript (e.g. Node.js)

Comment: @CodyCaughlan, do you [know of an alternative service that does work from a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369521/publish-data-from-browser-app-without-writing-my-own-server)?

Comment: WebSockets work, so something like Socket.io or Pusher.com should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you load your Javascript from the same SQS domain as you're trying to send to then no, due the clients/Javascript Same-Origin Policy you wont be able to cross post to SQS.

Your best bet is to use a middle-man server of your own.

Comment: actually, is there any way to format the output using json and wrapping it in a callback function?  if that were the case, then one can use jsonp to overcome cross domain limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS Javascript API in your JS app, and then use that library to make the SQS API call for you.