# Publish data from browser app without writing my own server

Tags: javascript, web-services, single-page-application

I need users to be able to post data from a single page browser application (SPA) to me, but I can't put server-side code on the host.

Is there a web service that I can use for this? I looked at [Amazon SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) (simple queue service) but I can't call their REST APIs from within the browser [due to cross origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393845/possible-to-send-request-directly-to-amazon-sqs-from-http-javascript-client).

I favour ease of development over robustness right now, so even just receiving an email would be fine. I'm not sure that the site is even going to catch on. If it does, then I'll develop a server-side component and move hosts.

Comment: I don't know the relationship between AWS and SQS, but Amazon [announced in August](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/08/31/amazon-s3-announces-cross-origin-resource-sharing-CORS-support/) that AWS [now supports CORS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html), which would mean you can do cross-origin Ajax requests with at least some AWS services.

Comment: @apsillers, thanks for the information but I can't seen anything that suggests it works for SQS. I'll keep looking and let you know if I find it.

Comment: You say that You don't have access to the code located on the host. Is it becuase the host doesn't belong to You or You just don't want to write server code? If it is the latter case maybe You should get interested in nodejs/express. I use a very simple implementation for jsonp using these two. I can provide You with code examples If You wish.

Comment: Cheers for the offer @op1ekun, I appreciate it. I've done a bit with Node/express before and yes, it's quite nice and simple. I am really just wondering whether it's possible to get generic data from a SPA to the site administrators without requiring custom server code.

Comment: This seems to be well supported. Read it here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only there are Web Services, but nowadays there are robust systems that provide a way to server-side some logic on your applications. They are called BaaS or [Backend as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service) providers, usually to provide some backbone to your front end applications.

Although they have multiple uses, I'm going to list the most common in my opinion:

- **For mobile applications** - Instead of having to learn an API for each device you code to, you can use an standard platform to store logic and data for your application.
- **For prototyping** - If you want to create a slick application, but you don't want to code all the backend logic for the data -less dealing with all the operations and system administration that represents-, through a BaaS provider you only need good Front End skills to code the simplest CRUD applications you can imagine. Some BaaS even allow you to bind some [Reduce algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) to calls your perform to their API.
- **For web applications** - When PaaS ([Platform as a Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service)) came to town to ease the job for Backend End developers in order to avoid the hassle of System Administration and Operations, it was just logic that the same was going to happen to the Backend. There are many [clones](http://firefeed.io/) that showcase the real power of this strategy.

All of this is amazing, but I have yet to mention any of them. I'm going to list the ones that I know the most and have actually used in projects. There are probably many, but as far as I know, this one have satisfied most of my news, whether it's any of the previously ones mentioned.

### [Parse.com](https://parse.com/)

Parse's most outstanding features target mobile devices; however, nowadays Parse contains an incredible amount of API's that allows you to use it as full feature backend service for Javascript, Android and even Windows 8 applications (Windows 8 SDK was [introduced](http://blog.parse.com/2012/10/25/introducing-the-parse-windows-8-sdk/) a few months ago this year).

*How does a Parse code looks in Javascript?*

Parse works through classes and objects (ain't that beautiful?), so you first create a specific class (can be done through Javascript, REST or even the Data Browser manager) and then you add objects to specific classes.

First, add up Parse as a script tag in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.15.min.js"></script>
```

Then, through a given Application ID and a Javascript Key, initialize Parse.

```
Parse.initialize("APPLICATION_ID", "JAVASCRIPT_KEY");
```

From there, it's all object manipulation

```
var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person"); //Person is a class  *cof* uppercase *cof* 
var personObject = new Person();
  personObject.save({name: "John"}, {
  success: function(object) {
    console.log("The object with the data "+ JSON.stringify(object) + " was saved successfully.");
  },
  error: function(model, error) {
    console.log("There was an error! The following model and error object were provided by the Server");
    console.log(model);
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

*What about authentication and security?*

Parse has a User based authentication system, which pretty much allows you to store a base of users that can manipulate the data. If map the data with User information, you can ensure that only a given user can manipulate specific data. Plus, in the settings of your Parse application, you can specify that no clients are allowed to create classes, to ensure innecesary calls are performed.

*Did you REALLY used in a web application?*

Yes, it was my tool of choice for a medium fidelity [prototype](http://jjperezaguinaga.github.com/UBC-CoursesWorklist/).

### [Firebase.com](https://www.firebase.com/)

Firebase's main feature is the ability to provide Real Time to your application without all the hassle. You don't need a [MeteorJS](http://meteor.com/) server in order to bring Push Notifications to your software. If you know Javascript, you are half way through to bring Real Time magic to your users.

*How does a Firebase looks in Javascript?*

Firebase works in a REST fashion, and I think they do an amazing job structuring the [Glory of REST](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). As a good example, look at the following Resource structure in Firebase:

```
https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users/fred/name/first
```

You don't need to be a rocket scientist to know that you are retrieve the first name of the user "Fred", giving there's at least one -usually there should be a UUID instead of a name, but hey, it's an example, give me a break-.

In order to start using Firebase, as with Parse, add up their CDN Javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
```

Now, create a reference object that will allow you to consume the Firebase API

```
var myRootRef = new Firebase('https://myprojectname.firebaseIO-demo.com/');
```

From there, you can create a bunch of neat applications.

```
var USERS_LOCATION = 'https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users';
var userId = "Fred"; // Username

var usersRef = new Firebase(USERS_LOCATION);
  usersRef.child(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    if (exists) {
        console.log("Username "+userId+" is part of our database");
    } else {
        console.log("We have no register of the username "+userId);
    }
  });
```

*What about authentication and security?*

You are in luck! Firebase [released their Security API](http://blog.firebase.com/post/38234264120/the-new-firebase-security-api) about two weeks ago! I have yet to explore it, but I'm sure it fills most of the gaps that allowed random people to use your reference to their own purpose.

*Did you REALLY used in a web application?*

Eeehm... ok, no. I used it in a [Chrome Extension](https://github.com/jjperezaguinaga/AIESEC-Chrome-Extension)! It's still in process but it's going to be a Real Time chat inside a Chrome Extension. Ain't that cool? Fine. I find it cool. Anyway, you can browse more awesome examples for Firebase in their [examples page](https://www.firebase.com/examples.html).

---

What's the magic of these services? If you read your [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [Mock Object Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object), at some point you can completely replace all of those services for your own through a REST Web Service provider.

Since these services were created to be used inside any application, they are CORS ready. As stated before, I have successfully used both of them from multiple domains without any issue (I'm even trying to use Firebase in a Chrome Extension, and I'm sure I will succeed soon).

Both Parse and Firebase have Data Browser managers, which means that you can see the data you are manipulating through a simple web browser. As a final disclaimer, I have no relationship with any of those services other than the face that [James Taplin](https://twitter.com/JamesTamplin) (Firebase Co-founder) was amazing enough to lend me some Beta access to Firebase.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you very much. I'm going to revisit this in the new year (only a few days away now) and I'll let you know how I get on.

Comment: Glad it helped, enjoy the holidays in the meantime :)

Answer (score 5):

You actually CAN use SQS from the browser, even without CORS, as long as you only need the browser to send messages, not receive them. *Warning: this is a kludge that would make my CS professors cry.*

When you perform a GET request via javascript, the browser will always perform the request, however, you'll only get access to the response if it was from the same origin (protocol, host, port). This is your ticket to ride, since messages can be posted to an SQS queue with just a GET, and who really cares about the response anyways?

Assuming you're using jquery, your queue is `https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/71717171/myqueue`, and allows anyone to post a message, the following will post a message with the body "HITHERE" to the queue:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/71717171/myqueue' +
       '?Action=SendMessage' +
       '&Version=2012-11-05' +
       '&MessageBody=HITHERE'
})
```

The'll be an error in the console saying that the request failed, but the message will show up in the queue anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)? That is one way of calling cross-domain scripts from javascript without running into the same origin policy. You're going to *have* to set up some script somewhere to send you the data, though. Javascript just isn't up to the task.

Comment: The problem there is that Amazon SQS doesn't seem to support the callback parameter needed for JSONP to work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending in what kind of data you want to send, and what you're going to do with it, one way of solving it would be to post the data to a Google Spreadsheet using Ajax. It's a bit tricky to accomplish though.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000020/ajax-post-to-google-spreadsheet) is another stackoverflow question about it.

If presentation isn't that important you can just have an embedded [Google Spreadsheet Form](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=87809).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sounds like it might work though I won't have a chance to test it for a few days. Also part of my data is a large (several MB) image, which can be either binary or base64 PNG encoded. Not sure if Google spreadsheets allow huge blobs of data.

Comment: For completeness, here's a link to the Spreadsheet API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: It seems that this option would require authentication details to be available within the web page in order to make the call to the server. This would allow anyone full access to the data store, which is not an option. I need unauthenticated writes and authenticated reads.

Answer (score 1):

What about `mailto:youremail@goeshere.com` ? ihihi

Meantime,  you can turn on some free hostings like `Altervista` or `Heroku` or somenthing else like them ..  so you can connect to their server , if i remember these free services allows `servers p2p`, so `you can create a sort of personal web services and push ajax requests as well`, obviously their servers are slow for free accounts, but i think it's enought if you do not have so much users traffic, else you should turn on some better VPS or Hosting or Cloud  solution.

Comment: Mailto links don't provide the best experience, and I might need to send a very long email body of base64 encoded image data.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid needing to think about hosting at all for now. The site is otherwise incredibly simple, so it seems like overkill. If such a service doesn't exist, it might make a nice product.

Comment: @DrewNoakes yep that's true, what about **http://pusher[dot]com** seems somenthing you could try

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CouchDB can provide what you're after. [IrisCouch](http://iriscouch.com/) provides free CouchDB instances. Lock it down so that users can't view documents and have a sensible validation function and you've got yourself an easy RESTful place to stick your data in.

Comment: Will it be possible to send data to their free DB instance from within the browser? Have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, it's a full CouchDB. Use the normal CouchDB APIs or an update function.